# Why is my solution wrong: How many functions are at most two to one?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, combinations

Let [n] denote the set {1, 2, ... ,n}. How many functions f : [5] --> [5] at most two to one?

There are 3 cases:

- Every integer is mapped to a distinct integer: $5!$
- Exactly one integer in co-domain has no pre-image: (5$*$4)$5 \choose 2$$3 \choose 1$$2 \choose 1$
- Exactly 2 integers in co-domain has no pre-image: ?

I am struggling calculating the last case.

1. I first choose 2 elements in the co-domain set that has 0 pre-images, $5 \choose 2$ = $5 \choose 3$ .
2. I chose 1 element in the domain that will map to the element in the range, that has only 1 preimage. So that makes $5 \choose 1$. Let's call this set of elements $x$.
3. I chose 2 elements in the domain that will map to the element in the range that has 2 preimages - $4 \choose 2$. Let's call this set of elements $y$.
4. Then, I chose the other 2 elements in the domain that will map to the element in the range that has 2 preimages - $2 \choose 2$. Let's call this set of elements $z$.

There are 3 slots in the range that will get integers mapped to:

- $a$, has 2 pre-images
- $b$, has 2 pre-images
- $c$, has 1 pre-images

Since $x$, $y$ and $z$ could be mapped to distinct slots $x$, $y$, and $z$, there are $3$.$2$.$1$ = $3!$ possible ways they could be mapped.

So that is:
[$5 \choose 3$ $*$ $3!$][$5 \choose 1$$4 \choose 2$$2 \choose 2$]

I know this is a rather complicated approach, however, I have been re-doing this over and over and cannot figure out which part is wrong. I also know there is a different solution, which is:

[$5 \choose 2$ $3 \choose 2$][$5 \choose 2$$3 \choose 2$]

But I would love to get some insight on why my solution is not correct.

Comment: It seems to me there should be cases, hence a sum.  A priori, you could have $0$ elements with $2$ preimages, exactly one element with $2$ preimages, or $2$ elements with $2$ preimages.  You need to count each case and add.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for the heads up! I forgot to add the previous cases. I edited for clarity.

Comment: I agree with the second solution.  I don't understand your method...in step $1$, you try to choose three elements with no pre-image, but there can only be two such.

Comment: My method:  Pick two elements which will have $2$ preimages, $\binom 52$ ways to do that.  Now pick two elements in the domain which will go to the lesser of those two, another $\binom 52$, then choose two other elements in the domain which will map to the greater, just $\binom 32$.  Now you've got one element left in the domain and three places to send it, so $3$.  Thus $\binom 52\times \binom 52\times \binom 32\times 3$ which coincides with your second answer.